# Report View Scrolling issue while displaying it in modal window

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog, report

First I open a Report criteria view(parent workspace) inside that I select the criteria such as TalentinShow, year and Show and click on getReport button, which shows report in modalwindow(smart-part) and if user scrolls downwards and close the report then while opening the report next time it shows the downward view. The view is not retain next time

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZSlo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rk5B.png)

enter code here
Report view:`enter code here`
                var talentInShowDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
                talentInShowDataSource.Name =            "CastingNDiversity_DomainModel_BusinessEntities_TalentInShow";
                talentInShowDataSource.Value = value;

```
            _reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            _reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(talentInShowDataSource);
            _reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "CastingNDiversity.Reports.ReportFiles.TalentInShowReport.rdlc";

            ResumeLayout(false);
            _reportViewer.RefreshReport();
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
public T ShowModalWindow<T>(T view, string title)
    {
        var info = new WindowSmartPartInfo
        {

            Modal = true,
            ControlBox = true,
            MinimizeBox = true,
            MaximizeBox = true,
            Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width * 2/3 ,
            Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height * 2/3 ,
            Title = title 

        };



            info.Keys.Add(WindowWorkspaceSetting.FormBorderStyle, FormBorderStyle.Sizable);
            info.Keys.Add(WindowWorkspaceSetting.StartPosition, FormStartPosition.CenterParent);

            ReportView._reportViewer.RefreshReport();
            WorkItem.Workspaces[WorkspaceNames.ModalWindows].Show(view, info);

            return view;


    }
```

if I use dispose method then next time I get Exception as:ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: ‘%name%’. `enter code here`

Comment: It's not really clear, what you are trying to do. Could you please describe the problem you have more thoroughly - and graspable?

Comment: my Rdlc report gets viewed in modalwindow(smart-part), so when i scroll down the report view and close it and again reopen it at that time it shows only the part that was there while closing the upper part is lost .